# Overriding "The speed of processor 0 in group 0 is being limited by system firmware"

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, cpu-speed

My Thinkpad automatically locks the CPU frequency to ~1,5Ghz while the adapter is plugged in without a battery, as described in [this article](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_CPU_frequency_scaling).

I don't care whether the adapter can support it or not (it has overcurrent protection anyway so there's no risk of hardware damage) and I successfully disabled this limitation on Linux by setting the `processor.ignore_ppc=1` kernel parameter. The problem is, I need this machine to run Windows applications, so I need an equivalent way of disabling that limitation on Windows.

On Windows, this generates the following event in the event log at boot time :

> The speed of processor 1 in group 0 is being limited by system firmware. The processor has been in this reduced performance state for 71 seconds since the last report.

I've already checked the power options, where I set the power plan to maximum performance and minimum CPU state to 100%. It didn't have any effect, most likely because this limitation is done at a lower level than the OS. Are there other solutions I could try ?

Comment: [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2288/throttlestop-6-00/) may be useful here.

Comment: The risk of hardware damage has nothing to do with overcurrent on the adapter. It has to do with inductance in the DC power line causing excessive voltage drop in the DC-to-DC converter (in the laptop) output leading to excessive current flow in the converter itself.